# ROS integration with motes

Tags: ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Suppose I'm running ROS on a Arduino Galileo controlled robot (since Galileo can run Linux I suppose it can run ROS)... And the Arduino platform is also connected to a ZigBee radio... How do I communicate with other such Galileo+ZigBee motes but not running ROS? Is it possible or do I have to install ROS on all the motes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188692/ros-integration-with-motes/) by [vreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/19867/vreg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Galileo can run ROS, but I've seen a fair number of questions and problems here on the discussion boards, and the [ROS Hydro on Galileo wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IntelGalileo/How%20to%20install%20ROS%20Hydro%20on%20Intel%20Galileo) also indicates that it is "Under construction and not yet ready for use." That said, I'm sure you can get ROS to run the Galileo, but it will take some perseverance and some elbow grease.

As for communicating with other "Motes" on a ZigBee network, ROS doesn't provide many tools there. If you have a specific application and protocol in mind already, you're probably best off writing your own translation node, which would run on the ROS Galileo and translate between ROS and your ZigBee network.

There is also the [rosserial_xbee](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_xbee) package, which provides some basic ROS messaging over XBee devices. I haven't used it myself, so I'm not sure how well-polished or stable it is, or how suitable it would be for your application.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1